# Use HP 2133 mininote as headless server

Tags: laptop, headless

I've got a dead HP 2133 mininote, and I think the issue is the GPU.  Apparently it's a well known fault.  I have the same symptoms:

- power light comes on
- no screen display
- the touchpad lock still lights up
- connected ethernet cable lights are on
- turn off, and the screen flashes

Rather than trying to fix it by applying heat to the GPU etc, I was wondering if I could use it as a headless server.

I removed the hard drive and installed Centos 6.5 with low graphics.  I setup a static Ip address and was able to sssh into it.

I then reinstalled the hard drive, but I can't hear the drive spin up, and I can't ssh into it.  The hard drive light does not flicker at all.  I double checked and the data cable is plugged back in again when I replaced the drive.  And of course no BIOS beeps in laptops.

Just wondering is there some sequence of keys I need to press ( tried F1 to continue etc in case it's the BIOS asking me to do something ) or what else I can do to get this going without stripping it down to fix the GPU.

Comment: Are you sure that it's a GPU issue and not something more serious? Sounds more serious than just that. *real* servers have serial port redirection just for this sort of scenario.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CKgOXtTqSgU I was thinking of using it for an asterisk server.  It has enough ram, and cpu for the purpose.